# Is it possible to have a ListViewGroup inside of a ListViewGroup in a C# ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewgroup

Is it possible to have a ListViewGroup inside of a ListViewGroup in a C# ListView?

I'm gathering all the files/folders on a drive with a ListView and want to separate them with ListViewGroup.  I have this code working fine.  But I'm not sure that I see any way to add a group within a group.

For example:

```
Group "C:\AMD"
  Files in folder
  Group "C:\AMD\Lib"
  Files in folder
Group "C:\Windows"
  Files in folder
  ...etc
```

I am able to get each folder in its own group fine - I just thought it would be nice to have a subgroup like you see with TreeView.

Comment: then why not use a treeview?

Comment: Im doing other things that require a columns.  I have seen some source code available that sorta combines a ListView and TreeView but I can live without this feature for less complication.  More or less looking to confirm an answer of Yes or No to the question

Comment: Use MVVM with a hierarchy of ViewModels that better represents your structure and use DataTemplates and a DataTemplateSelector to control what UI to show depending on the item type in your tree structure

Comment: here you go.. http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html - google is nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `ListViewGroups` cannot nest.

You can use a [TreeListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-use-a-treelistview)

[image]